# How to avoid change of line color i Dash app when options are selected/deselected

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm trying to write a Dash app with a line plot with multiple lines. Each line represents an option from a Checklist list. My issue is, that as options are selected/deselected line color of all lines changes. How can I assure that the line for each value remains the same?

Here is the code for the app:

```
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SANDSTONE])
server = app.server

SERVER_HOSTNAME = os.environ.get("DATABRICKS_SERVER_HOSTNAME")
HTTP_PATH = os.environ.get("DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH")
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ.get("DATABRICKS_TOKEN")

CATALOG_NAME = "vip_data"
DB_NAME = "dqm"
TABLE_NAME = "uptime"

connection = sql.connect(
    server_hostname=SERVER_HOSTNAME, http_path=HTTP_PATH, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
)

cursor = connection.cursor()

cluster_list = pd.DataFrame(
    cursor.execute(
        f"SELECT DISTINCT cluster FROM {CATALOG_NAME}.{DB_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} WHERE cluster NOT IN ('dev', 'tst')"
    ).fetchall()
)[0].to_list()

cursor.execute(
    f"SELECT date,cluster,up_pct FROM {CATALOG_NAME}.{DB_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} ORDER BY date"
)
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
df.columns = ["date", "cluster", "up_pct"]

today = date.today()


app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row([html.H1("K8s Uptime Dashboard")]),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        dbc.Row(
                            [
                                dbc.Label("Select date"),
                                dbc.RadioItems(
                                    options=[
                                        {"label": "Recent", "value": today},
                                        {
                                            "label": dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                                                id="date-picker",
                                                min_date_allowed=date(2023, 7, 1),
                                                max_date_allowed=today,
                                                initial_visible_month=today,
                                                date=today,
                                                display_format="YYYY-MM-DD",
                                                first_day_of_week=1,
                                                style={
                                                    "font-size": "8px",
                                                    "display": "inline-block",
                                                },
                                            ),
                                            "value": 1,
                                        },
                                    ],
                                    value=today,
                                    id="radio-data-picker",
                                ),
                            ]
                        ),
                        dbc.Row(
                            [
                                dbc.Col(
                                    [
                                        dbc.Label("Select clusters"),
                                        dbc.Checklist(
                                            cluster_list,
                                            cluster_list,
                                            id="cluster-checklist",
                                        ),
                                        html.Button(
                                            className="button btn btn-primary btn-sm",
                                            id="all-or-none1",
                                            n_clicks=0,
                                            children="Select/Unselect All",
                                        ),
                                    ]
                                ),
                            ]
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id="uptime-line-figure",
                            style={"width": "70vw", "height": "80vh"},
                        )
                    ]
                ),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)


@callback(Output("uptime-line-figure", "figure"), Input("cluster-checklist", "value"))
def update_figure(cluster_list):
    df_filtered = df[df["cluster"].isin(cluster_list)]

    fig = px.line(df_filtered, x="date", y="up_pct", color="cluster", title="Uptime")

    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have no idea how to proceed with above. I expect the color of each option to remain constant no matter how many options are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Problems is solved. The solution was creating a dict of assigned color to each of the clusters and the adding color_descrete_map to px.line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).